# MongoDB Realm not syncing data to atlas with flexible sync

Tags: mongodb, react-native, synchronization, realm, mongodb-realm

I am trying to create a proff of concept for my team with Realm sync but the data is not syncing to the atlas server(it is getting created locally). I have just created a react-native template and all the code that I am trying to work with is in the app.js in the root.

App.js -

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Realm from "realm";
import type {Node} from 'react';
import {useApp,createRealmContext} from '@realm/react';
import {AppProvider, UserProvider, useUser} from '@realm/react';

import {
  Button,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
  Alert,
  TextInput
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';


const userSchema = {
  name: "users",
  primaryKey: '_id',
  properties: {
    __v:  "int?",
    _id:"objectId?",
    createdAt: "date?",
    device_token:"string?",
    device_type:"string?",
    email:"string?",
    ever_logged_in:"bool?",
    firstname:"string?",
    isLoggedin:"bool?",
    lastname:"string?",
    login_type:"string?",
    password:  "string?",
    phone:  "string?",
    relationship:"string?",
    social_id:  "string?",
    status: "string?"
  },
}


let user;
const ATLAS_SERVICE = 'mongodb-atlas';
const app = new Realm.App({id: 'test-eyyda'});

async function anonymousLogin() {
  let user;
  try {
    const app = new Realm.App({id: 'test-eyyda'}); // pass in the appConfig variable that you created earlier
    const credentials = Realm.Credentials.anonymous(); // create an anonymous credential
    user = await app.logIn(credentials);
    console.log(user);
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
      throw `Error logging in anonymously: ${JSON.stringify(error,null,2)}`;
  }
}

const Section = ({children, title}): Node => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionTitle,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          },
        ]}>
        {title}
      </Text>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionDescription,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.light : Colors.dark,
          },
        ]}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};


const login = async (email,password) => {
  
  const credentials = Realm.Credentials.emailPassword(email, password);
  try {
    user = await app.logIn(credentials);
    console.log(app.currentUser,user.id);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Failed to log in", err);
  }
};

const logout = async () => {
  
  const userId = app.currentUser.id;
  await app.allUsers[userId].logOut();
  console.log(app.currentUser);
  let email_div = $("#user-emails");
  email_div.empty();
  let realm_BE_firstname = $("#realm-BE-firstname");
  realm_BE_firstname.empty();
  $('#user').empty();
  localStorage.clear();
};

// const realm = await Realm.open(
//   schema: [userSchema],
//   sync: {user, flexible:true},
// );

 

const getUsersRealmFunction = async () => {
  // console.log(user.id);
  try {
    const result = await user.functions.getUsers();
    const get2 = result.slice(0,2);
    console.log(result);
    // let email_div = $("#user-emails");
    // let realm_BE_firstname = $("#realm-BE-firstname");
    // realm_BE_firstname.empty();
    // email_div.empty();
    // for (const user of get20) {
    //   let p = document.createElement("p");
    //   p.append(user.firstname);
    //   realm_BE_firstname.append(p);
    }catch (error) {
    // $("#user").append("Need to login first.");
    console.error("Need to log in first", error);
    return;
  }
}

const openRealm = async () => {
  console.log('openRealm clicked');
  try {
    const realm = await Realm.open({
      schema: [userSchema],
      sync: {
        user: app.currentUser,
        flexible: true,
      },
    });

    console.log('realm',realm, realm.subscriptions);

    // await realm.subscriptions.update((mutableSubscriptions) => {
    //   mutableSubscriptions.add(
    //     realm
    //       .objects(userSchema.name)
    //       // .filtered("location = 'dallas' && price < 300000 && bedrooms = 3", {
    //       //   name: "home-search",
    //       // })
    //   );
    // });

    let x = realm.objects("users");
    console.log(x);
    realm.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Failed to open the realm", err.message);
  }
}

const test1 = async () => {
  try {
    console.log(app.currentUser.id);
    const config = {
      sync: {
        user: app.currentUser,
        flexible: true,
        initialSubscriptions: {
          update: (subs, realm) => {
            subs.add(
              realm.objects("users")
              // .filtered("name == 'Developer Education'")
            );
          },
        },
      },
    };
    const realm = await Realm.open(config);
    // const realm = await Realm.open({
    //   schema: [userSchema],
    //   sync: {
    //     user: app.currentUser,
    //     flexible: true,
    //     initialSubscriptions: {
    //       update: (subs, realm) => {
    //         // subscribe to all of the logged in user's to-do items
    //         subs.add(realm.objects('users'));
    //       },
    //     }  
    //   },
    // });

    await realm.subscriptions.update((mutableSubscriptions) => {
      mutableSubscriptions.add(
        realm.objects('users'),
        // {
        //   name: "users",
        //   throwOnUpdate: true,
        // }
        )
    });

    console.log(realm.subscriptions.state);

    let myusers = await realm.objects("users"); 
    console.log('users',myusers);

    console.log(realm.subscriptions);


    // const subscriptions = realm.subscriptions;
    // console.log(subscriptions);

    

    

    realm.write(() => {
        
        realm.delete(realm.objects("users"));
        
        
      });
      myusers = await realm.objects("users"); 
      console.log('emptyusers',myusers);
    
    let datas1;
    realm.write(() => {
        datas1 = realm.create("users", { firstname: "Masffdx", email: "tessfdft@gamils.com"  });
      });
    myusers = await realm.objects("users"); 
    console.log('users',myusers);

    // await realm.subscriptions.update((mutableSubs) => {
    //   mutableSubs.add(myusers, {
    //     name: "myusersSubs",
    //     throwOnUpdate: true
    //   })
    // });  


    // // console.log(y, realm.subscriptions);
    // });  


    // realm.write(() => {
    //   datas1 = realm.create("users", { firstname: "Masfdx", email: "tessdft@gamils.com" });
    // });
    // const myusers = await realm.objects("users"); 
    // console.log(myusers);



  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

}


const test = async () => {
  console.log(app.currentUser.id);
  try {
    const realm = await Realm.open({
      schema: [userSchema],
      sync: {
        user: app.currentUser,
        flexible: true,
        initialSubscriptions: {
          update: (subs, realm) => {
            // subscribe to all of the logged in user's to-do items
            subs.add(realm.objects('users'));
          },
        }  
      },
    });

    
    let myusers = await realm.objects("users");
    console.log(myusers);
    
    
    // console.log(realm.subscriptions);

    realm.write(() => {
      realm.delete(realm.objects("users"));
    });

    myusers = await realm.objects("users"); 
    console.log('emptyusers',myusers);
        
    let datas1;
    realm.write(() => {
        datas1 = realm.create("users", { firstname: "Masffdx", email: "tessfdft@gamils.com"  });
      });
    myusers = await realm.objects("users"); 
    console.log('users',myusers);

    // await realm.subscriptions.update((mutableSubscriptions) => {
    //   mutableSubscriptions.add(
    //     realm.objects('test.users'),
    //     {
    //         name: "users",
    //         throwOnUpdate: true,
    //       }
    //       )
    // });
    console.log(realm.subscriptions);
    console.log(realm.subscriptions.state);

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}


const App: () => Node = () => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  const [email,setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password,setPassword] = useState("");
  // const app = useApp();

  const data = () =>{
    console.log('data');
    Alert.prompt('Enter email',[
      {
        text:"Submit",
        onPress:((text)=>setEmail(text))
      }
    ],"plain-text","email")
    console.log(email);
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'} />
      <ScrollView
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        style={backgroundStyle}>
        <View>
          <TextInput
            style={{height: 40}}
            placeholder="email"
            onChangeText={newText => setEmail(newText)}
            defaultValue={email}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={{height: 40}}
            placeholder="password"
            onChangeText={newText => setPassword(newText)}
            defaultValue={password}
          />
          <Button
            title="Login"
            // onPress={() => Alert.alert('Simple Button pressed')}
            onPress={() => {
              login(email,password)
            }}
          />
          <Button
            title="logUsers"
            // onPress={() => Alert.alert('Simple Button pressed')}
            onPress={() => {
              getUsersRealmFunction()
            }}
          />
          <Button
            title="openRealm"
            // onPress={() => Alert.alert('Simple Button pressed')}
            onPress={() => {
              openRealm()
            }}
          />
           <Button
            title="test"
            // onPress={() => Alert.alert('Simple Button pressed')}
            onPress={() => {
              test()
            }}
          />
          
        </View>  
        {/* <Header /> */}
        {/* <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          }}>
          <Section title="Step">
            Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.js</Text> to change this
            screen and then come back to see your edisfdts.
          </Section>
          <Section title="See Your changes">
            <ReloadInstructions />
          </Section>
          <Section title="Debug">
            <DebugInstructions />
          </Section>
          <Section title="Learn More">
            Read the docs to discover what to do next:
          </Section>
          <LearnMoreLinks />
        </View> */}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
});

// export default App;
export default App;
```

The function realm.subscriptions is returning undefined. Not sure how to check if the subscription is valid.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project but reviewing an entire application goes beyond the scope of SO. Also, questions should generally include the problematic code along with the troubleshooting so we can understand the use case. Also - links can break and if that happens, it would make the question useless to future readers. Please review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - update and clarify the question with your code and we'll take a look!

Comment: Done and done :) Please have a look @Jay

Comment: I think you overlooked the 'minimal' part of [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as that's a lot of code for use to parse though! That being said, I think you're having an asynchronous issue in that you've got synchronous code accessing vars that will be populated asynchronously - therefore outputting `realm.subscriptions` will be nil because it's not populated yet. You may want to add breakpoints and step through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected